# Next block of code execute earlier before the fetch how can I fixed that

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

It should have given me not null output but I am getting null output. It is working fine if I console inside the block of code but outside it gives me null value
Here is the code:

```
app.post("/downloadDb",async (req,res)=>{
 var docData = [];
 var idList = [];
  console.log("downloadBd");
  const mahafuzCol = firestore.collection("Mahafuz")
  await mahafuzCol.listDocuments()
  .then( listDoc=>{
   //List of id fetch 

    listDoc.forEach(data=>{
      idList.push(data.id)
    });
  }).catch(e=>console.log(e));


  //document is fetched 
  await idList.forEach(id=>{
    mahafuzCol.doc(id).get().then(
      doc=>{
        docData.push(doc.data());
        //Here I get desire output w=if I log with console
      }
    );
  });

//Here I get null output
  await console.log(docData);
});
```

Comment: You can not await on a console.log() :)

Comment: You dont need to await a promise with .then() either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, looking at your piece of code, I would like to point out a few things.

1. You are using the latest and greatest ES7 async and await feature which is great. Why are you stuck with the old way of defining variables? Try to use let and const instead of var. Don't mix the ECMAScript versions like this. This is considered a bad practice.
2. Loops in Node.js are synchronous as of now (though asynchronous loops are in the pipeline of Node and we would see them soon). You cannot put asynchronous code inside a loop and expect them to work as expected. There is a whole concept of `event loop` in Node.js and how Node handles asynchronous tasks. So, if you have time, you should definitely go through the `event loop` concepts.

Here is the better way to write the code:

```
app.post('/downloadDb', async (req, res) => {
  // always wrap asynchronous code in async/await in try/catch blocks
  console.log('downloadBd');

  const mahafuzCol = firestore.collection('Mahafuz');

  try {
    // assuming that listDocuments returns a promise
    // await on it until it gets resolved
    // all the listed documents will be assigned to docs
    // once the promise is resolved
    const docs = await mahafuzCol.listDocuments();

    const idList = docs.map(data => data.id);

    // again assuming that get() returns a promise
    // pushing all the promises to an array so that
    // we can use Promise.all to resolve all the promises
    // at once
    const promisesList = idList.map(id => mahafuzCol.doc(id).get());

    // fetching document is here
    // once all the promises are resolved, data contains
    // the result of all the promises as an array
    const data = await Promise.all(promisesList);

    const docData = data.map(doc => doc.data());

    console.log(docData);

    // return some response
    return res.status(200).send();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error: ', error);

    // return some response
    return res.status(500).send();
  }
});
```

PS:
If you still somehow want to use asynchronous loops, have a look at this library
https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each

Answer (score 0):

Since forEach is async in nature, as soon as you write a promise in a forEach() loop. The next command gets executed, which in your case is:

```js
// Here I get null output
await console.log(docData);
```

You'd need the typical for loop for this task:

Try the snippet below:

```js
let idListLen = idList.length;

for (let i =0; i< idListLen; i++) {
  mahafuzCol.doc(id).get().then(
    doc=>{
      docData.push(doc.data());
      //Here I get desire output w=if I log with console
    }
  );
}

console.log(docData) //prints the list of data
```